# print data from simple api in angular 8

Tags: angular, api

I have an API URL below i have to print data on my html component please let me know method how to print .
I have following method so i have to print string eg. page_tilte

```
resData;
newsdata;

ngOnInit() {
const url="https://tiavik.com/maken/api/aboutUs";
this.http.get(url).subscribe(res=>{
  this.resData=res;
  this.newsdata=this.resData.Data
  console.log(res);
})
```

I am using this in my html:-

```
<div class="h3 block-title" *ngIf="newsdata">
<div *ngFor="let news of newsdata">
  {{news?.page_title}}
</div>
</div>
```

please let me know what should i do ?...

Comment: Seeing the response from the URL, it seems the property you're looking for is `data` and not `Data`. Property names are case sensitive. Replace `this.newsdata=this.resData.Data` with `this.newsdata=this.resData.data`.

Comment: i am getting this:- Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Comment: The response is an object. `*ngFor` by default can loop only over arrays/lists. You could use `keyvalue` pipe to loop over objects. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding from my comment, two changes are needed.

1. The response object from the URL has the property `data` not `Data`. Property names are case-sensitive so it should be accessed through `this.newsdata=this.resData.data`.
2. The response is an object and not an array. To loop over an object using the `*ngFor` directive you could use the `keyvalue` pipe.

Controller

```js
resData;
newsdata;

ngOnInit() {
const url="https://tiavik.com/maken/api/aboutUs";
this.http.get(url).subscribe(res=>{
  this.resData = res;
  this.newsdata = this.resData.data;
  console.log(res);
});
```

Template

```html
<div class="h3 block-title" *ngIf="newsdata">
  <div *ngFor="let news of newsdata | keyvalue">
    {{ news.key }} - {{ news.value }}
    <!-- to print specific values (eg. 'page_title') -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="news.key === 'page_title'">
      {{ news.value }}
    <ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response of API is just an object then instead of iterating we can directly read data from object like below code snap.

```
result;

ngOnInit() {
 const url="https://tiavik.com/maken/api/aboutUs";
 this.http.get(url).subscribe(res=>{
 this.result = res.data;
});
```

Read data directly form `result` in template.

```
<div class="h3 block-title">
 {{ result.page_title }}
</div>
```

Comment: i am trying to use above:_ data does not exits on type object getting this msg

Comment: @user3021146 can you print `console.log(res)` and share the response so that we can have better idea what actually the response is.